# What is the best way to approach my boss for a temporary/permanent position rather than freelancing without offending him?

Tags: job-change, freelancing

I joined the small company I work in now 4 months ago as a freelancer. My aim is to be a temporary or permanent employee there. Recently, one of my bosses left and my other boss took over his job responsibilities. But I can see that he is pressured with all of this. I think that he will be recruiting somebody to help him soon. I was thinking that I should let him know that I'm interested. I mean you can't get what you don't ask for, right? I'm intending to this right after holidays. What is the best way to approach my boss?

Note: we're in two different countries and I don't mind moving to the company's country.

Edit to add details: I want to know how to approach my boss for this position without making him feel like he is incompetent for doing the new tasks.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't ask, you don't get.

1. Tell him point blank that if he is looking to fill a bona fide temporary/full time position, that you are available as a candidate. Make it simple and direct. Don't beat around the bush. Don't mull. Don't agonize. Don't make it into something that's more more complicated than it is, because it's not complicated. Get it done, and get it out the way.
2. And ideally, tell him BEFORE and hopefully not just before he sets the wheels into motion that he is officially looking for a candidate.
3. It doesn't matter how you approach him and tell him, as long as the end result is that he now knows that you are interested and you are available as a candidate for the position.

Comment: well... the OP should be polite!

Comment: @bharal What other people call "polite" would cause me a brain blockage and on occasion, a brain aneurysm. If you are working for me, you have the right to initiate a non-urgent conversation with me as  long as you don't catch me in the middle of a high priority, high urgency task. Tell me what you want, just get it out. It's not as if I have all day to wait on you until you decide to say something. My attitude is that if you have to worry about being polite, then you are not naturally polite and you have to make an explicit effort to be polite. I am glad that I don't have that problem.

Comment: @bharal If you have a good degree of decency and I know you to be a considerate type, you don't have to worry about me considering you impolite. If you interrupt me in the middle of an important task, I'll give you the benefit of the doubt that you have a pretty good reason for doing what you do.